# How to combine geom_tile with plotly for interactive grid chart in R

Tags: r, plotly

I am new to using plotly and would like to create an interactive graph that is built similarly to a heat map. I would like to combine the geom_tile() function from ggplot with the ggplotly() function from plotly to create a ggplot and convert it into a plotly object. Here's an example of my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
nrows <- 70
var <- mpg$class  # the categorical data 
df <- expand.grid(y = 1:nrows, x = 1:nrows)
categ_table <- round(table(var) * ((nrows*nrows)/(length(var))))
df$category <- factor(rep(names(categ_table), categ_table))   

## Plot
test_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = category)) + 
  geom_tile(color = "black", size = 0.2)

ggplotly(test_plot)
```

Given the dimensions (nrows = 70), the ggplotly object lags significantly when created. When I set nrows = 10, there is no lag. I was wondering if my use of geom_tile() combined with ggplotly is correct here, or if there is a better way for me to do this?

Could I do this by building the plotly object directly, with plot_ly()? It looks like plot_ly() has a 'heatmap' type.

EDIT - I have a small number of discrete categories, which makes me think I cannot do this with plot_ly's heatmap. I am not sure.

Comment: Are you getting the desired output using `geom_tile`? Is it only the *speed* of rendering?

Comment: Yes. But I think I've found the better way to do this with plot_ly heatmaps

Comment: I will post an update on this soon